# PHP Session Values always one submission behind. How to get current values?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Have a project where a user fills out a succession of forms in a multi-step process.  Each of the form screens have a next/back button that does an AJAX call and does a POST to a PHP controller.  The PHP Controller then writes the form data to SESSION.

I need to insert a test for a certain state.  Let's say the user selects 'California' as a state.  If so, then they are taken OUT of the flow and shown another page that is an error/info page.  Part of the functionality of this page is that it needs to take the stored Session values and write to a MySQL table (first_name, last_name, email)

So far so good. Part of my confusion is WHERE is the proper place to test for this value.  Since we are MVC, I could test for it at the AJAX/JS level, or do the test in the controller.  I chose to just test directly after the POST:

```
 // If the customer has chosen CA as a state we must stop process
 if ($('#employee_state_origin').val() == 'CA') {
     PAGE_STATUS.destination = 'error-page';
 }
```

The code uses PAGE_STATUS.destination as a way to keep track of what page is coming up next, what page is behind, etc. etc.  Basically a keep-alive sort of history.

The problem is this.  Once I do this test, of course the POST has already happened, and the controller puts the values in SESSION like so:

```
private function storeUserData(&$posted_data, &$user_input)
    {
        if ($this->response_body->has_error) {
            return;
        }

        //If we just got data posted from employee entrance and it already exists - we need to reset all the data
        if ($posted_data->step === 'employee_entrance' && !empty($_SESSION[SELF::SESSION_KEY][$posted_data->step])) {
        $_SESSION[SELF::SESSION_KEY] = array();
    }

    if ($posted_data->step === 'member_information' || $posted_data->step === 'physician_information') {
        $user_input->createCustomObject($posted_data);
        $_SESSION[SELF::SESSION_KEY][$posted_data->step][] = $posted_data;
    } else {
        $_SESSION[SELF::SESSION_KEY][$posted_data->step] = $posted_data;
    }
}
```

After the data is posted and written into SESSION the page redirects and shows the error page.  On the error page, I am writing procedural code to dump into a MySQL table.

The issue is when I first start the browser, of course the Session is empty.  I go to the form, put in first_name, last_name and email and then hit Next... the Ajax call happens, the POST values are good, the Session gets written....

But after the redirect, on the error page I have to start the session...

```
session_start();
$first_name = $_SESSION['wonderousBooksProject']['employee_entrance']->employee_first_name;
```

The problem is $first_name is empty when echo-ing it out as well as the other values.  If I go to the page again, and put in different information and then go to the error page again.... it prints out the PREVIOUS ENTRY.

So, it's saving the session information, but my target page will not retrieve the latest entry...it retrieves the one previous.

Anyone have a thought about what is happening.  I have used session_destroy() to end session,  session_write_close(), and lots of other things, but cannot understand why it writes the session value the first time, shows it as blank, then the next entry is persona non grata and it displays the previous one?

Comment: How are you doing the redirect? It sounds like you're not waiting for the AJAX request to complete before you do it. It needs to be done in the callback function of the AJAX call.

Comment: We verified through the post data that the correct info is being submitted via POST, the AJAX call completes and it DOES write the value to Session.  But when reading it the first time everything is null and it writes a null record to the database.  But on the second time through, I see that it retrieves the session vars but they are not the current form data I just entered.... it's the previous entry.  It has to be how I am reading the data.  Just don't understand why it doesn't get the latest entry into session, but the previous one.

Comment: There must be something asynchronous going on, so the redirect is being processed before the AJAX request actually completes, and because of that it uses the previous value of the session variable.

Comment: Post the code that does the AJAX request and redirect.